# Merge folders by moving their files and folders recursively

Tags: powershell

There are two folders: test1 and test2. Both have the same structure and files and extensions but different content.
I want to move (merge) all folders and files from test1 folder into with compliancing with their structure to another folder.

test1 and test2 folders structure

```
D:\test1\friends\1.txt
D:\test1\graphics\1.txt
D:\test1\public\1.txt
D:\test1\resource\1.txt
D:\test1\servers\1.txt
D:\test1\steam\1.txt
```

Comment: `Move-Item "D:\test1\*" "D:\test2"` -- does this do what you want?

Comment: It'll just move all files to the folder's root.

Comment: It works for me. Remove the `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object`. Call only `Move-Item`.